# Insert Value into DateTime field Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am writing an `Insert into` statement using dynamic SQL in this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTransaction]
    @UpdateType             Int,
    @BillCode               Char(17),
    @PatientName            Varchar(max),
    @MobileNo               Varchar(20),
    @Address                Varchar(max),
    @BillDate               DateTime,
    @BedFrom                Date,
    @BedTo                  Date,
    @OTType                 Char(3),
    @OTMedicineCharge       Decimal(18,2),
    @WardMedicineCharge     Decimal(18,2),
    @MonitorUsed            Int,
    @OxygenUsed             Int,
    @PulltionUsed           Int,
    @ECGUsed                Int,
    @PathologyCharge        Decimal(18,2),
    @DressingType           Char(3),
    @NebuligerUsed          Int,
    @DoctorFees             Decimal(18,2),
    @AnaesthisistCharge     Decimal(18,2),
    @AsstOfScFees           Decimal(18,2),
    @AttendentTime          Int,
    @OtherChargesCode       Char(5),
    @AcYr                   Char(4),

    @Error Varchar(50)      Output,
    @OutBillCode Char(17)   Output
AS
BEGIN
    IF DATEDIFF (Day, GETDATE(), @BillDate) < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Error = 'Backward Entry Date is not permitted'
        RETURN
    END

    IF LEN(@OtherChargesCode) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @OtherChargesCode = '00000'
    END

    DECLARE @temptableName CHAR(21)
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @tempBillNo CHAR(7)
    DECLARE @tempBedCharge DECIMAL(18,2)
    DECLARE @OTCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @MonitorCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @OxygenCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @PulltionCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @ECGCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @DressingCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @NebuligerCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @AttendentCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @OtherCharge Decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @TotalCharge Decimal (18,2)
    DECLARE @GrandTotal Decimal(18,2)

    Set @tempBedCharge = (DATEDIFF(Day,@BedFrom,@BedTo) + 1)*(Select BedCharge from ChargesMast)
    Set @OTCharge = (Select OTCharge from OTTypeMast Where OTType = @OTType)
    Set @MonitorCharge = (Select MonitorCharge From ChargesMast)*@MonitorUsed
    Set @OxygenCharge = (Select OxygenCharge From ChargesMast)*@OxygenUsed
    Set @PulltionCharge = (Select PulltionCharge From ChargesMast)*@PulltionUsed
    Set @ECGCharge = (Select ECGCharge From ChargesMast)*@ECGUsed
    Set @DressingCharge = (Select DressingCharge From DressingTypeMast Where DressingType = @DressingType)
    Set @NebuligerCharge = (Select NebuligerCharge From ChargesMast)*@NebuligerUsed
    Set @AttendentCharge = (Select AttendentCharge From ChargesMast)*@AttendentTime

    Set @TotalCharge = @tempBedCharge + @OTCharge + @OTMedicineCharge + @WardMedicineCharge + @MonitorCharge + @OxygenCharge
                            + @PulltionCharge + @ECGCharge + @PathologyCharge + @DressingCharge + @NebuligerCharge + @DoctorFees
                            + @AnaesthisistCharge + @AsstOfScFees + @AttendentCharge

    Set @OtherCharge = (Select isNULL((select ChargeValue From OtherChargesMast Where OtherChargeCode = @OtherChargesCode),0))

    Set @GrandTotal = @OtherCharge + @TotalCharge

    Set @temptableName = 'TransactionDetail' + @AcYr
    If @UpdateType = 1
    Begin
        Set @tempBillNo = (Select Right('00000' + Cast(isNull(MAX(BillNo),00000) + 1 as varchar),5)  from TransactionDetail1819)
        Set @OutBillCode = 'BILL/' + @AcYr + '/' + 'N'+ '/' + @tempBillNo 

        Set @sql = 'Insert into ' + @temptableName + '(BillCode,BillNo,PatientName,MobileNo,Address,BillDate,BedFrom,BedTo,BedCharge,OTType,
                                        OTCharge,OTMedicineCharge,WardMedicineCharge,MonitorUsed,MonitorCharge,OxygenUsed,OxygenCharge,PulltionUsed,
                                        PulltionCharge,ECGUsed,ECGCharge,PathologyCharge,DressingType,DressingCharge,NebuligerUsed,
                                        NebuligerCharge,DoctorFees,AnaesthisistCharge,AsstOfScFees,AttendentTime,AttendentCharge,
                                        Total,OtherChargesCode,GrandToTal)

                            values(' + @OutBillCode +',' + @tempBillNo +','+ @PatientName +',' + @MobileNo +',' +@Address+',' + @BillDate + ',' + @BedFrom +',' + @BedTo +',' +@tempBedCharge+',' +
                            @OTType + ',' + @OTCharge +',' + @OTMedicineCharge + ',' + @WardMedicineCharge + ',' + @MonitorUsed + ',' +@MonitorCharge +',' + @OxygenUsed +',' +@OxygenCharge +',' +
                            @PulltionUsed +',' + @PulltionCharge+ ',' + @ECGUsed + ',' + @ECGCharge + ',' + @PathologyCharge + ',' + @DressingType + ',' + @DressingCharge + ',' + @NebuligerUsed + ',' +
                            @NebuligerCharge + ',' + @DoctorFees +',' + @AnaesthisistCharge + ',' +@AsstOfScFees+ ',' + @AttendentTime + ',' + @AttendentCharge + ',' +@TotalCharge + ',' +
                            @OtherChargesCode + ',' + @GrandTotal + ')'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql


    End



    If @UpdateType = 3
    Begin
        EXEC('Delete @temptableName Where BillCode = @BillCode')
        Set @OutBillCode = @BillCode
    End
End
```

And Passing value as :

```
Private Sub Data_Manipulate(ByVal updateType As Integer)
        If Update_Status() = True Then
            Try
                sqlCon = New SqlConnection(myDataClass.myConnectionString)
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "spTransaction"
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("UpdateType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateType
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("BillCode", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtBillCode.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PatientName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("MobileNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMobile.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("BillDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dTPDate.Value
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("BedFrom", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dTPBedFrom.Value
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("BedTo", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dTPBedTo.Value
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("OTType", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cboOTType.SelectedValue
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("OTMedicineCharge", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtOTMedicineCharge.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("WardMedicineCharge", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtWardMedicineCharge.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("MonitorUsed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtMonitorUsed.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("OxygenUsed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtOxygenUsed.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PulltionUsed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtPulltionUsed.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("ECGUsed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtECGUsed.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PathologyCharge", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtPathologyCharge.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("DressingType", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cboDressingType.SelectedValue
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("NebuligerUsed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtNebuligerUsed.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("DoctorFees", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtdoctorFees.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("AnaesthisistCharge", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtAnaesthisist.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("AsstOfScFees", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Val(txtAssistantOfScFees.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("AttendentTime", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(txtAttendent.Text)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("OtherChargesCode", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtOtherChargeCode.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("AcYr", SqlDbType.Char).Value = mAcYr

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Error", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
                sqlCmd.Parameters("@Error").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@OutBillCode", SqlDbType.Char, 17)
                sqlCmd.Parameters("@OutBillCode").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

                If sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    sqlCon.Open()
                End If
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                If Len(sqlCmd.Parameters("@Error").Value.ToString()) <> 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show(sqlCmd.Parameters("@Error").Value.ToString(), mAppName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    dTPDate.Select()
                    If sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        sqlCon.Close()
                    End If
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                txtBillCode.Text = sqlCmd.Parameters("@OutBillCode").Value.ToString()

                btnPrint.Visible = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, mAppName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Reset_Text()
            Finally
                sqlCon.Close()

            End Try
            Set_Buttons(True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

bUT iT IS GIVING ME ERROR : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How Can I pass the date fields to avoid error?

I tried all references but no success.

Comment: Oh wow... that SQL is absolutely terrifying I'm afraid; it's wide open to SQL injection. it's effectively a security flaw just waiting to be exploited. You clearly know that parametrising is a thing though, as you do it in your C#. The problem, however, is that you haven't parametrised your SQL. You need to do that **and** quote those dynamic object names.

Comment: Remove that `sp_executesql` and the concatenated query string. Just execute the `INSERT` statement. What you did is convert the integers, dates etc into localized strings and then try to convert them back. Probably in the wrong order too

Comment: I'm also impressed that SQL like `SET @MonitorCharge = (SELECT MonitorCharge FROM ChargesMast) * @MonitorUsed;` is working. I would expect an error complaining about the subquery returning more than 1 row.

Comment: *I just noticed that `@Address` and `@PatientName` are both `varchar(MAX)` datatypes. A malicious person injecting could **literally** do anything with a variable of that size.*

Comment: @Larnu The Chargemast table is restricted to insert more than one value

Comment: Do you mean that `ChargesMast` can never have more than 1 row?

Comment: Yes. It is restricted from code behind

Comment: @Kanavos I tried that also but that is giving error: Incorrect syntax near

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ***untested*** however, I suspect this will get you in the right place. If this still isn't working, then I suspect that the order of the columns in the `INSERT` don't make the values provided for the in the `VALUES` clause. I haven't checked that, but `PRINT`/`SELECT` @SQL will help you here.

Anyway, here I've parametrised your SQL and think I got the datatypes correct, so *hopefully* that does the job:

```
SET @sql = N'
INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@temptableName) + N'(BillCode,
                            BillNo,
                            PatientName,
                            MobileNo,
                            Address,
                            BillDate,
                            BedFrom,
                            BedTo,
                            BedCharge,
                            OTType,
                            OTCharge,
                            OTMedicineCharge,
                            WardMedicineCharge,
                            MonitorUsed,
                            MonitorCharge,
                            OxygenUsed,
                            OxygenCharge,
                            PulltionUsed,
                            PulltionCharge,
                            ECGUsed,
                            ECGCharge,
                            PathologyCharge,
                            DressingType,
                            DressingCharge,
                            NebuligerUsed,
                            NebuligerCharge,
                            DoctorFees,
                            AnaesthisistCharge,
                            AsstOfScFees,
                            AttendentTime,
                            AttendentCharge,
                            Total,
                            OtherChargesCode,
                            GrandToTal)
VALUES (@OutBillCode, @tempBillNo, @PatientName, @MobileNo, @Address, @BillDate, @BedFrom, @BedTo, @tempBedCharge, @OTType, @OTCharge, @OTMedicineCharge, @WardMedicineCharge, @MonitorUsed, @MonitorCharge, @OxygenUsed, @OxygenCharge, @PulltionUsed, @PulltionCharge, @ECGUsed, @ECGCharge, @PathologyCharge, @DressingType, @DressingCharge, @NebuligerUsed, @NebuligerCharge, @DoctorFees, @AnaesthisistCharge, @AsstOfScFees, @AttendentTime, @AttendentCharge, @TotalCharge, @OtherChargesCode, @GrandTotal);';
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                           N'@OutBillCode char(17), @tempBillNo char(7), @PatientName varchar(MAX), @MobileNo varchar(20), @Address varchar(MAX), @BillDate datetime, @BedFrom date, @BedTo date, @tempBedCharge decimal()18,2), @OTType char(3), @OTCharge decimal(18,2), @OTMedicineCharge decimal(18,2), @WardMedicineCharge decimal(18,2), @MonitorUsed int, @MonitorCharge decimal(18,2), @OxygenUsed int, @OxygenCharge decmial(18,2), @PulltionUsed int, @PulltionCharge decimal(18,2), @ECGUsed int, @ECGCharge decimal(18,2), @PathologyCharge decimal(18,2), @DressingType char(3), @DressingCharge decimal(18,2), @NebuligerUsed int, @NebuligerCharge decimal(18,2), @DoctorFees decimal(18,2), @AnaesthisistCharge decimal(18,2), @AsstOfScFees decimal(18,2), @AttendentTime int, @AttendentCharge decimal(18,2), @TotalCharge decimal(18,2), @OtherChargesCode char(5), @GrandTotal decimal(18,2)',
                           @OutBillCode =  @OutBillCode,
                           @tempBillNo =  @tempBillNo,
                           @PatientName =  @PatientName,
                           @MobileNo =  @MobileNo,
                           @Address =  @Address,
                           @BillDate =  @BillDate,
                           @BedFrom =  @BedFrom,
                           @BedTo =  @BedTo,
                           @tempBedCharge =  @tempBedCharge,
                           @OTType =  @OTType,
                           @OTCharge =  @OTCharge,
                           @OTMedicineCharge =  @OTMedicineCharge,
                           @WardMedicineCharge =  @WardMedicineCharge,
                           @MonitorUsed =  @MonitorUsed,
                           @MonitorCharge =  @MonitorCharge,
                           @OxygenUsed =  @OxygenUsed,
                           @OxygenCharge =  @OxygenCharge,
                           @PulltionUsed =  @PulltionUsed,
                           @PulltionCharge =  @PulltionCharge,
                           @ECGUsed =  @ECGUsed,
                           @ECGCharge =  @ECGCharge,
                           @PathologyCharge =  @PathologyCharge,
                           @DressingType =  @DressingType,
                           @DressingCharge =  @DressingCharge,
                           @NebuligerUsed =  @NebuligerUsed,
                           @NebuligerCharge =  @NebuligerCharge,
                           @DoctorFees =  @DoctorFees,
                           @AnaesthisistCharge =  @AnaesthisistCharge,
                           @AsstOfScFees =  @AsstOfScFees,
                           @AttendentTime =  @AttendentTime,
                           @AttendentCharge =  @AttendentCharge,
                           @TotalCharge =  @TotalCharge,
                           @OtherChargesCode =  @OtherChargesCode,
                           @GrandTotal =  @GrandTotal;
```